# PDO Connection Class using singleton pattern

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, singleton

```
<?php

//db connection class using singleton pattern
class dbConn {
    //variable to hold connection object.
    protected static $db;

    //private construct – class cannot be instatiated externally.
    private function __construct()
    {

        try { // assign PDO object to db variable
            self::$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cricket', 'root', '');
            setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch (PDOException $e) { //Output error – would normally log this to error file rather than output to user.
            echo "Connection Error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    // get connection function. Static method – accessible without instantiation
    public static function getConnection()
    {
        //Guarantees single instance, if no connection object exists then create one.
        if (!self::$db) { //new connection object.
            new dbConn();
        }
    //return connection.
    return self::$db;
    }
}
//end class

?>
```

please check this error if i call this parameters in index like

```
    $sql = "select * from user";
    $q = dbConn::getConnection()->query($sql);

   $result =  $q->fetch();
    print_r($result);
}
```

tutorials link : http://weebtutorials.com/2012/03/pdo-connection-class-using-singleton-pattern/

Comment: What error are you getting exactly?

Comment: ( ! ) Fatal error: Class 'dbConn' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\kazim\test2\index.php on line 4
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0006 329488 {main}( ) ..\index.php:0

Comment: i am flowwing this tutorial but its not working http://weebtutorials.com/2012/03/pdo-connection-class-using-singleton-pattern/

Comment: That sounds like the connection class declaration is not present at runtime. If you use automatic inclusion (ClassPath) then maybe it is not stored in those paths. Or you simply forgot to include it...

Comment: sidenote: [Who needs Singletons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595964/who-needs-singletons/4596323#4596323)

Comment: You must include the script file that class dbConn is defined in index.php. Add the following to the beginning of **index.php** : `include('dbConn.php');`

Comment: i include('dbConn.php'); it but not working

Comment: please test this tutotrial : http://weebtutorials.com/2012/03/pdo-connection-class-using-singleton-pattern/

Answer (score 6):

Your code has several issues (aside from usefulness of singleton pattern in PHP):

The idea of a singleton is that the *instance* is referenced by a private static variable, which isn't the case in your code, you reference an instance of a PDO object. A *true* singleton version of your code would have to look like this:

```
class TrueSingleton
{
    private static $_instance;
    private $_pdo;

    private function __construct()
    {//private constructor:
        $this->_pdo = new PDO();//<-- connect here
        //You set attributes like so:
        $this->_pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        //not setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);<-- PHP can't know which setAttribute method to call on what object
    }
    public static function getConnection()
    {
        if (self::$_instance === null)//don't check connection, check instance
        {
            self::$_instance = new TrueSingleton();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }
    //to TRULY ensure there is only 1 instance, you'll have to disable object cloning
    public function __clone()
    {
        return false;
    }
    public function __wakeup()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The rest is pretty basic, apart from, whenever you need to query the DB, you'll have to use `$this->_pdo->query()` inside the member functions

Comment: ( ! ) Fatal error: Class 'dbConn' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\kazim\test2\index.php on line 4

Comment: your Singleton misses `__wakeup()` which means it can be unserialized

Comment: @KazimKing: does your index.php start with a line of code like `require_once('path/to/dbConn.php');` or does it contain a _working_ `__autoload()` function? PHP does need the class definition before it can use it, obviously. Check for typo's in the name, too. Also: don't use the `?>` closing tag in php class definition files

Comment: error in this code  class TrueSingleton
public static getConnection() - not working

Comment: <?php
require_once('dbConn.php');
$db = dbConn::getConnection();
?>  not working

Comment: @KazimKing: well obviously, the constructor isn't a working example, and the `self::$_instance` variable isn't properly initialized to null. You'll have to add some of your own code to get this working

Comment: @KazimKing: Have you defined this class in a file called `dbConn.php`, and is it in the same directory as `index.php`? if not: then it stands to reason that php can't find it. Read [the require_once docs](http://www.php.net/require_once), or write [an autoloader function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php)

Comment: all files in same folder